# Laravel/Larasponse/Eager Loading - Better way to implement this?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I am currently in the process of learning Laravel 5 by doing a small project. I come from CodeIgniter and have some programming experience in other languages as well.

For this project I have a few Eloquent models setup;

```
Exercise -> has many variations
Variation -> belongs to exercise

User -> is creator of exercise and/or variation
```

I am using Larasponse and have written some transformers for each entity, as I want to create a flexible API.

To use 'eager' loading I have been playing around with Fractal and the 'ParseIncludes' function, and created a ApiController that handles this for you. For each controller that extends the ApiController you can set $IncludeOptions that relate to that specific resource, and passing that to a function to get eloquent eager loaded relations.

So far it works, but I was wondering if I am doing something really stupid or if there is a better/cleaner way to implement this into the ApiController and it's child-classes..

https://gist.github.com/EdwinMeijne/1fd103fbf8f903ce58bc

Care to take a look?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: well checkout the gist -> it is working but I was wondering if there is a better way: as an inexperienced programmer I might miss something others immediately spot.